# Python3.5 virtual envirement not working ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've installed Python 3.5 on my VPS Ubuntu.

Command:

```
python3.5 --version
```

Gives:

```
3.5.0+
```

and then I install simple Flask application and install virtual environment and activate it:

```
virtualenv -p python3.5 envname
source envname/bin/activate
```

But if I print Python version, it returns 3.4.3

```
from flask import Flask
import sys
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return sys.version
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This part:

```
sys.executable
```

Returns:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

Not 3.5.

Comment: You create an environment called `envname` and activate one called `venv`.

Comment: im recreate virtualenv, but version still 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) [GCC 5.2.1 20151010]

Comment: im run  virtualenv -p python3.5 envname
and run source envname/bin/activate

Comment: but version still 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) [GCC 5.2.1 20151010]

Comment: can u help me pls?

Comment: When using Python >= 3.3 you don't need virtualenv module anymore and actually should use [pyvenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: what i can doing what use 3.5 version?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of workaround, but the simplest solution that comes to my mind:

```
cp envname/bin/python3.5 envname/bin/python
```

That way even if Python scripts are executed with `python` command it will use Python 3.5.

Comment: where i can run this?

Comment: In the terminal obviously. Just like you have ran `source envname/bin/activate` to activate your virtualenv.